# Show which 301 redirects are in google chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

can i somehow chrome to get all the URLs for which google chrome has 301 redirects cache, I know how to clear the 301 redirects cache I want to see which URLs actually google chrome has 301 caches?